# How to solve trascendental equation with a singularity

Tags: plotting, equation-solving, intersection

I have to solve a trascendental equation that behaves as

```
-csch(ax) == x-3
```

which grafically looks like

[image]

As you can see, when $a$ gets bigger the csch gets closer to the axis. Since it is divergent for $x=0$, I can't plot it at $x=0$ exactly so eventually, as $a$ gets bigger and bigger I will miss the lower intersection. The red line is a plot for $a=1000000$ and, as you can see, I can't really see the lower intersection anymore, altough I know that it has to be there somewhere.

Note: The function I'm working its not a $csch(x)$ but a complicated integral that has similar behaviour. My problem is that I don't actually know  that the lower intersection exists for all values of $a$. Opposite to the $csch(x)$ example where I know the function analitically, I only know the integral numerically so when $a$ gets really big I don't know if the lower intersection trully dissapears or if it is there but I need to get closer to $x=0$.

**How can I improve the precision by which I obtain the lower intersection up to bigger values of a?**

Comment: This looks like a question about some language other than Mathematica.

Answer (score 2):

```
Prepend[Table[
   {a, x /. Solve[-Csch[a*x] == x - 3, x, Reals][[1]] // N}, {a, 
    10^Range[0, 8]}],
  Style[#, 14, Bold] & /@ {"a", "x"}] // Grid[#, Alignment -> Right] &
```

[image]

**EDIT:** Using [`FindRoot`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FindRoot.html)

```
Prepend[Table[
   {a, x /. FindRoot[-Csch[a*x] == x - 3, {x, 10^-(1 + Log10[a])}]}, {a, 
    10^Range[0, 8]}],
  Style[#, 14, Bold] & /@ {"a", "x"}] // Grid[#, Alignment -> Right] &
```

[image]

With other equations, if [`WorkingPrecision`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/WorkingPrecision.html) is a problem then specify a value rather than using machine precision (default).

Comment: Thanks! What if x<0 is not a valid domain of the function? How would you rescrict the domain of the Solve/FindRoot ?

Comment: You can include constraints in `Solve` or `Reduce` or `NSolve`. With `FindRoot` you have to use a different starting point.